# The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state

Tags: core-service, cme

Just started seeing the following error in the CME when trying to open any component or page:

> The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state. Do you want to close this window?

[image]

Why is this happening all of a sudden?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because the CoreService (the Windows TCM Host Service Service) is not running. Check configuration of TCMServiceHost.exe.config and restart the TCM Host Service.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this error message once.  We have restarted the machine and the Core Service Webservice wasn't available.

Ensure the web service is running and this should fix it.

Thanks

John

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, one possible cause is that the service host is not running. The message, however, is simply saying that the channel is "in a faulted state", so it's quite possible that something else has gone wrong server side. If starting the service host doesn't help, I'd suggest going through the logs on the server to see if any errors show up.